# Getting user information from customer ADFS

Tags: adfs, openid-connect, claims

I have the following setup:

-We have a ADFS 4.0 (win 2016) running.

-Customer has ADFS 3.0 (win 2012R2). (configured as claim provider trust with our ADFS).

-The customer ADFS have configured the following claim rules for the relying party trust (on their ADFS):

[image]

I have configured the same claim rules for the Application group WEP API application as "Passthrough or filter an incoming claim" adding all scopes.

I am using the openid-connect "Authorization code flow" using something like

```
https://{sts_token_service}/adfs/oauth2/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={uri}/&scope=openid+profile+allatclaims+email+user_impersonation&nonce=nonce
```

AND

```
https://{sts_token_service}/adfs/oauth2/token/
?grant_type=authorization_code
&code={code}
&resource={resource}
&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={uri}
&scope=openid+profile+allatclaims+email+user_impersonation
```

I am getting a valid access token just fine, that can be used access the protected api, but I really need the claims as well and I only get upn, but not the others.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: I can see in my .well-known/openid-configuration that the claims are not in the list of supported claims. Might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same situation which works.

You need pass-through rules on the CP and on the OIDC RP.

Comment: It turns out that there was an error on the side of the claims provider. One of the claims that we tried to return was identified by an urn rather than a namespace. Removing that claims insured that the others were returned. eg. The ClaimType 'urn:oid:2.5.4.12' must be of format 'namespace'/'name'.